Nintendo Entertainment System LED mod
I was wondering if/how it'd possible to mod a frontloader NES (traditional NES design with the front door hinge) with an LED that activates when opening the front door hinge, but the power to the console itself isn't engaged. So when your just opening the consoles door you'd have a light on the inside before inserting a cartridge and powering on the console? Thanks so much for any information!
apparently i needed to clarify further what my question was asking so ill reiterate?
I refurbish/modify broken NES consoles. I had the idea for adding an LED that activates when you open the cartridge door to the console to insert a game cartridge.
This LED would be inside the shell of the NES emitting light inward into the interior of the console housing, seperate from the power on LED indicator. I would intend on using a white LED for this. However, this would require the LED to receive power from the NES unit itself without the power switch being activated to circumvent the need of said LED from having its own power supply. I'm sure id have to connect this to some type of magnetic switch/sensor to activate the power or complete the circuit to the LED.
I was hoping to ask if this idea is feasible, and if so what components would be required to do this; Also, to where I might need to connect these components.

The answer is probably something a little more sophisticated than, "find standby power, solder a wire from there to your LED strip, and use a normally on button to toggle the LEDs to turn on when you lift the lid".

This isn't that bad of a question, I don't think. There's more-or-less only one way of doing it simply, so it's not opinion-based, and doesn't need any clarity. It's clear.

Your writing is still unclear on the details. Does the LED shine into the cartridge area to illuminate it for visibility or does it point outward as an indicator light similar to the normal power LED? How do you plan on sensing if the door is open or closed, or is it OK to always keep the LED on since it’s for illumination purposes (like asked in the previous question)? What color LED do you intend to use?

i've tried to make it clear as possible with my last edit with addressing your questions ste kulov. Maybe what I am asking in the wrong place, as this is a pretty specific question pertaining to an older piece of technology not everyone is familiar with.
